# Create new Response from base64 image data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, png, response

I want to fake a response. I have the base64 string data of a `png` image. Now I want to make a response but It does not work.

My code:

```
const data = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...";
const res = new Response(data, {
      status: 200,
      statusText: "OK",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
        "Content-Length": data.length
      },
    });
```

I did some research, and it seems like `base64` can not just be passed to response body. It needs to be converted to a buffer or something like that.

It can be done in NodeJS like this `Buffer.from(data, 'base64')`

But my code is in the browser only.

Is there any way that I can implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

base64 is an encoded string, to get the actual image you need to convert it to binary data using `atob`. here is an example:

```
const b64String = data.split(',')[1];
var byteString = atob(b64String);
var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}
var imageBlob = new Blob([intArray], {type: 'image/png'});
const res = new Response(imageBlob, {
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
    "Content-Length": imageBlob.size
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.to/ionic/converting-a-base64-string-to-a-blob-in-javascript-35kl

```
const base64Response = await fetch(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Data}`);
```

easy as that.

And you can set additional headers by recreating the Response object and using the result of `.blob()` as body:

```
new Response(await base64Response.blob(), {
    status: 200,
    statusText: "OK",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
        ...
    }
})
```